# How do I determine statistical significance value where the entire population gets the intervention and the results seem profoundly significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval

Of course, finding the statistical significance for a value in a typical population containing both an intervention group and a control group is elementary.

However what if we consider the control group to be every single data point leading up to the experiment, essentially an infinite number of control data points?  Normally such a study is defined as having no placebo group, but for purposes of describing the significance of the findings, we should be able to define a placebo group as being all phenomena outside of (leading up to) the intervention. Yes?  How does that math look?

Here's a real world example.  50% of patients with sepsis-shock will die ... this is common knowledge.  It has always been so.  So:

- Control Group: essentially infinite # of data points and ave. death rate = 50%

We discover a protocol that cures 90% of cases, and do this protocol for 200 patients (only 20 die).

- Intervention Group: 200 data points (people), and the average death rate = 10%

This seems significant but the medical world says it's meaningless because there is no control group defined within the experiment.  How can we assign some sort of value representing the significance of the vastly improved outcome?  There has to be some kind of math to do this. Having a parameter that demonstrates the level of this statistical significance in these cases could have profound effects on medicine.

It seems especially indisputable in cases where there is a best-case ceiling (in the case of Sepsis) that is consistently being surpassed by a certain intervention.  The fact that this is ignored in medicine is unconscionable, yet nobody is willing to put their foot down and demand a more Hippocratic approach.

This is actually a real world problem, where there are just a handful of hospitals that use the new protocol, and 1000's of hospitals that refuse to because they are waiting for RDBPC experiments, which to date have been botched (do not match the life-saving protocol), meanwhile 300+ people needlessly die in the US every day from sepsis.  10,000 every day throughout the world.  Those who would do an RDBPC study *correctly* (using correct protocols) either don't have the resources or they consider it unethical (which it would be) when they know they can prevent 80% more sepsis deaths than conventional protocol causes.

Comment: You seem to be making your way to the idea of a **one-sample test.** Also: welcome to CV.

Comment: "RDBPC" stands for "randomized, double-blind, placebo control". I doubt that double-blind studies would be feasible or that anyone would consider use of  a placebo control ethical in trialling sepsis treatments: it's probably just randomized, active control trials that have been performed or are being advocated.

Comment: Alexis - I did some youtubes on one-sample test to figure out what this means ... yes this exactly describes this situation.  I can solve for T and compare that to the t.95.  Thank you!

Comment: Scortchi - You're right ... what was done was just an RCT, my bad.  Even so, and RCT seems unethical (because it still gives a seemingly obvious inferior treatment to the control group yielding an expected higher death rate).  So using a T-test (that Alexis mentioned) for those hospitals using the new protocol should be the preferred analysis, yes?

Comment: @Alexis was answering the general question: in this particular case the appropriate one-sample test would be of the null hypothesis that the probability parameter of a binomial distribution is equal to 0.5. The assumption that patients presenting with sepsis at the particular hospitals that offer the new treatment have the same prognosis as patients as any other hospital is likely questionable, however. A two-sample observational study controlling for factors known or thought to affect mortality would be  the next best thing to an RCT.

Comment: And note that if it's quite plausible that those factors account for all the apparent benefit of the new treatment, an RCT needn't be considered unethical, according to the principle of clinical equipoise.

Comment: I'm not sure I exactly understand Scortchi ... the factors to which you refer are those that are common between both study groups?  That then makes sense to me, but if preliminary data suggests strongly that the benefit is due to the intervention then we don't have clinical equipoise and the RCT looses it's status as an ethical study, yes?

Comment: The question's whether the preliminary data do in fact strongly suggest that there's a benefit from the new treatment when you take into account that age, sex, comorbidity, onset-to-door time, severity of symptoms, &c. affect a patient's risk of death, & differ on average between patients presenting at different hospitals. "Taking into account" could be purely a matter of medical judgement, or of collecting data to estimate the difference in treatment outcomes adjusted for these factors.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* compare a very large sample (here essentially the whole population) considered as a treatment group with a traditional, 'well-known', or'standard' value. That would be a one sample test. Not a two-sample test of treatment vs placebo.

For the results to be worthwhile, it must really be true that the standard value is the generally accepted value for formerly untreated subjects from the same population.

However, you are not likely to get universal agreement about the continuing applicability of the standard value. Someone might argue that factors other than your treatment
have intervened to change that standard value. (Global warming, political strife, antibiotic resistance, etc.)

The question you need to ask yourself is why go to the
trouble and expense of treating the entire population, when you might get about the same result (reject or not) by treating part of the population and comparing that part with the untreated part. There is nothing quite as universally satisfying and convincing as a randomized trial of a control group vs. a placebo group.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for.  Thank you so much!  Youa re also correct that the standard value is up for debate.  I suppose I could use the value that would give me the least significant result for the T-test, and if even that results in say ... a  T.99 value, then nobody can argue with that.  Is that the right thing to call it, a "t.99 value", for values in the bottom or top 1%?

Comment: Also I agree a 2-sample t-test does seem more "satisfying" and "convincing", but in it is unethical to withhold a clearly life-saving treatment from any terminally ill person. Also, this example seems the poster child for the special case where a one-way T-test across enough hospitals should be considered superior evidence to mandate a change in procedure across all hospitals: We have a dozen hospitals doing it for 3+ years, averaging a 90% survival compared to 50% standard survival over that same 3 year period. RCTs aren't infallible, in fact they *were* done, and incorrectly, a huge setback.